# HTML5 video loading in Ionic LoadingController

Tags: android, html, typescript, ionic-framework, video

I have a HTML5 video element which is showing mp4 video in LoadingController(Ionic framework). My problem is that video is not immediately loaded after loader is shown, I can see the default thumbnail/poster of html5 video element for 0.2s and just after this is video shown. The problem occurs just on Android device, iOS devices are playing video instantly.

[image]

Loader initialization code:

```
var preloaderOptions: object ={
  spinner: 'hide',
  duration: 2500,
  message: `
      <div class="custom-spinner-container">
        <div class="custom-spinner-box">
          <video id="videoPlayer" autoplay muted loop playsinline webkit-playsinline preload="metadata">
              <source src="./assets/videos/loader.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
          </video>
          <p>`+loaderMessages[Math.floor(Math.random()*loaderMessages.length)]+`</p>
        </div>
      </div>`,
  cssClass: 'custom-loading'
};

this.preloaderController.create({...preloaderOptions}).then((preloader) => {
    this.preloader = preloader;
    preloader.present().then(el => {
      let video = this.preloader.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
      video.autoplay= true;
      video.playsInline = true;
      video.muted = true;
      video.loop = true;
      video.preload="metadata";
      video.webkitPlaysInline = true;
      video.play();
    });
  });
```

I also tried to place poster image into video markup and typescript, but not helped to get rid of default thumbnail. Preload="auto" wasn't working too.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I fixed it by adding white poster jpg picture, but the key is to show video just before calling play() method.

```
this.preloaderController.create({...preloaderOptions}).then((preloader) => {
        this.preloader = preloader;
        let video = this.preloader.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
        video.style.display = "none";
        preloader.present().then(el => {
          video.autoplay= true;
          video.playsInline = true;
          video.muted = true;
          video.loop = true;
          video.preload="auto";
          video.poster = "./assets/images/loader_poster.jpg";
          video.style.display = "inline-block";
          video.webkitPlaysInline = true;
          video.play();
        });
      });
```